# Assistance with htaccess redirect in Wordpress Network for 1 page on every site in the network

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am attempting to make a 301 redirect for one page that exists on every site in my network without having to write 200+ "Redirect 301" statements.  I'm trying to learn a bit here, as it seems that mod_rewrite or Redirect Match could assist me, but I am a bit green in these areas.

The pseudo language of what I would need done:
301 redirect http://url.com/sitenameA/products-services/old-product/   to  http://url.com/sitenameA/products-services/

301 redirect http://url.com/sitenameB/products-services/old-product/   to  http://url.com/sitenameB/products-services/

So, where "sitenameA" and "sitenameB" are part of the URI, they must be preserved in the redirect, and take the user to the products-services page instead of the old-product page of the respective site.

As it is a Wordpress network site, there is only ONE htaccess (no ACTUAL directories) for each of the sites.

The answer to this problem was kicked off by the SO'er below.  For SEO purposes, if you come across this problem, the answer is:

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/products-services/sms-texting/?$ /$1/products-services/ [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in each of the `sitenameA` and `sitenameB` directories?

Comment: As it is a Wordpress network site, there is only ONE htaccess (no ACTUAL directories) for each of the sites nor is there actual pages or directories.  It's all virtually delivered.  The main (only) htaccess file lives in the root of the Wordpress installation/root of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule as **first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/products-services)/old-product/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/products-services/old-product/?$ /$1/products-services/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried this.  Doing so caused a network-wide 500 Internal Server Error :(  I placed it as the first rule in the htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry there was a misplaced bracket. Fixed it now. Please try again.

Comment: I modified your source though and found out if I dropped your paranetheses after products-services and added products-services after the /$1 we had success!!!!  Here's my final, working code:  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/products-services/old-product/?$ /$1/products-services/ [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Just needed products-services after the /$1 or else it just took them to the homepage of the site.  Got it!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yes that will also work fine, I was trying to use `products-services` on both sides and attempting to capture `siteA/products-services` in `$1`